# MediaElement not playing mp3

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to play mp3 file using MediaElement control.

If I put this control directly on my main wpf window, it's working.

But now I'm want to create a class and playing the mp3.  So I have a class :

```
 class Player
    {
        private MediaElement media;
        public MediaElement MyMedia
        {
            get { return media; }
            set { media = value; }
        }


        public Player()
        {
            media = new MediaElement();
            media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            media.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\Music\yumeji.mp3",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            media.Play();
        }


    }
```

But it's not working.

EDIT:

I use this code,

```
  MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
  m.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\Music\yumeji.mp3"));
  m.Play();
```

When i use this, it is play mysound for 3 second and then stop .

Answer (score 1):

In order to work MediaElement must be part of the logical tree.

Indeed if you add it to a panel, something like, then it will work

```
Player p = new Player();
myGrid.Children.Add(p.MyMedia);
```

This is why it works if you put it in a `Window`

However if you simply want to play mp3 without adding it to the logical tree, then you could achieve that with the [naudio library](http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3).

Comment: Yes, If I put this control directly on my window, it's working, but if i add a MediaElement in a class , it is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i don't want to use any dll.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was you need to hold a reference to the MediaPlayer.  It was garbage collected.